# What is the code for a key in sublime text

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, sublime-text-3

How do I find out what the name for the key is so I can add it to the keybindings file in sublime?

I am trying to create a key binding for spell check as
`ctrl+<the f6 key without having to push fn>`.
Currently `ctrl+f6` finds spelling errors. But to do that I have to push `ctrl+f6+fn`. I want to only push `ctrl+<the f6 key without having to push fn>` without changing any keyboard settings for the os.

Comment: Open the ST console ``ctrl+` `` and write `sublime.log_input(True)`. This logs the key inputs.

Comment: That is the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible, at least not with the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key involved. Every other meta-key should work fine.

> The Fn key is a form of meta-modifier key, in that it causes the operating system to see altered scancodes when other keys on the keyboard are pressed. This allows the keyboard to directly emulate a full-sized keyboard, so the operating system can use standard keymaps designed for a full-sized keyboard. **However, because the operating system has no notion of the Fn key, the key can not normally be remapped in software, unlike all other standard keyboard keys.**
>
> via [Wikipedia](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Fn_key)